# AngularJS changes the url depending on method (Get, Put)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-headers

I'm using factories in Angular to bind ajax requests to my web api. The factory looks like this.

```
app.factory('QuestionContainer', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
return $resource('http://localhost:52133/api/questioncontainerapi/:id', null,
    {
        'update': { method: 'PUT' },
        'publish': { method: 'Put', url: 'http://localhost:52133/api/questioncontainerapi/:id/Publish/' }
    });
}]);
```

As you can see I've put `:id` between two actions in the url and the method is currently `Put`. If I in my controller use the factory like this ->

```
QuestionContainer.publish({ id: 1 });
```

the request url beocmes `http://localhost:52133/api/questioncontainerapi/Publish/` with a body of `{ id: 1 }`. If I instead use the `Get` method the request url changes to `http://localhost:52133/api/questioncontainerapi/1/Publish/`, this is the url I want.

How can I make Angular understand this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the param, try with the following code:

```
app.factory('QuestionContainer', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
return $resource('http://localhost:52133/api/questioncontainerapi/:id', {id: '@id'},
    {
        'update': { method: 'PUT' },
        'publish': { method: 'Put', url: 'http://localhost:52133/api/questioncontainerapi/:id/Publish/' }
    });
}]);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rahpuser/m6pqu3k7/1/)

in console you can see the requests

**Explanation**

url: /some/:param

Param must be defined, so we say `{param: 'text'}`, in this case the url would be resolve to `/some/text` always..

But if we want to have dynamic urls based on variables we specify:`{param: '@p'}`
Where p is a variable that belongs to the instance resource or to the data object you pass to a class resource.

```
QuestionContainer.publish({ id: 1 }); // {id: 1} is the data object
```

So if we want the /some/3 we do it like the following:

```
QuestionContainer.publish({ p: 3 }); // class
var question = new QuestionContainer({p: 3}); // or new QuestionContainer(); question.p = 3;
question.$publish();
```

The official page could extend more in this: [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

Comment: Works! Why do I have to do like this?